# How to list and filter by custom field in product archive page

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, filter

I am developing a site where I want a custom filter on the archive page which contains values of some custom fields let's say logo_color.

For example, product 1 has logo_color "black" and product 2 has logo_color "white" and so on. So I want to display "logo_color" with options like "black", "white"... in the custom filter.

Now, I want to filter product data by that field. For example, If I select logo_color "white" then only products having logo_color "white" will be displayed in the archive page.

Can anyone help me how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what's your post type, but something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key'   => 'logo_color',
    'meta_value' => 'white'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```